# Hibernate how to discriminate in joined-subclass

Tags: hibernate

Supposing I have the following case of Entity model and using Hibernate 3.6:

```
Person
    |__ Student
            |__ SchoolBoy
            |__ CollegeStudent
```

The tables I have in my DB are **tperson** and **tstudent**. As I'm using hibernate mapping files, I declare it as below into my Person entity definition:

```
<joined-subclass name="Student" table="tstudent">
    <key column="id_person" />
</joined-subclass>
```

Being SchoolBoy similar to CollegeStudent, I want to use the same table for both (tstudent), having a **student-type** discriminator column, while I keep both of the classes. My problem is that Hibernate doesn't seem to allow discriminator columns once you're into a joined-subclass.

Is there a workaround for that?

**UPDATE**

That's what I have right now:

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="Id" column="id" type="integer">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <joined-subclass name="Student" table="tstudent">
        <key column="id_person" />
        <joined-subclass name="SchoolBoy" table="tschoolboy">
            <key column="id_person" />
        </joined-subclass>
        <joined-subclass name="CollegeStudent" table="tcollegestudent">
            <key column="id_person" />
        </joined-subclass>
    </joined-subclass>
</class>
```

That's what I would like to have in the join part of the mapping:

```
<joined-subclass name="Student" table="tstudent">
    <key column="id_person" />
    <discriminator column="student_type" />
    <subclass name="SchoolBoy" discriminator-value="SCHOOL_BOY" />
    <subclass name="CollegeStudent" discriminator-value="COLLEGE_STUDENT" />
</joined-subclass>
```

Comment: please share complete mappings

Comment: I'll follow up later when I had time to look up the specifics, but I solved this by exchanging inheritance for composition between Person and Student - being a student is merely a role of a person in this case.

Comment: Updated with more detail of my mapping file. @mabi if you have a solution I'll be grateful if you post some example based in my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Hibernate documentation says:

> Hibernate does not support mixing `<subclass>`, `<joined-subclass>` and `<union-subclass>` mappings under the same root `<class>` element. It is possible to mix together the table per hierarchy and table per subclass strategies under the the same `<class>` element, by combining the `<subclass>` and `<join>` elements

In your case, you would be required to move the discriminator column to the `tperson` table and use join elements to add extra properties to you student classes.

```xml
<class name="Person" table="tperson" discriminator-value="PERSON">
    <id name="Id" column="id" type="integer">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <discriminator column="person_type" />
    <subclass name="Student" discriminator-value="STUDENT">
        <key column="id_person" />
        <subclass name="SchoolBoy" discriminator-value="SCHOOL_BOY">
            <join table="tstudent">
                <key column="id_person" />
                ...
            </join>
        </subclass>
        <subclass name="CollegeStudent" discriminator-value="COLLEGE_STUDENT">
            <join table="tstudent">
                <key column="id_person" />
                ...
            </join>
        </subclass>
    </subclass>
</class>
```

You can also probably add a join in the Student subclass element for the properties that are common to all students

Comment: I knew it wasn't possible to mix class inheritance types, however, didn't notice about the chance of mixing discriminator values at different levels. That definitely deserves the bounty.

Comment: I would be grateful if you have a look to a [topic-related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542729/hibernate-subclasses-many-to-many-using-the-same-pivot-table) I'm dealing with.