# Hibernate many-to-many with subclasses using the same pivot table

Tags: java, hibernate

Having this model schema:

```
Person
    |__ Student
            |__ SchoolBoy
            |__ CollegeStudent
```

I'm using Hibernate 3.6 and I use the **tperson** table for all the classes, using a discriminator column. My mapping is done like that:

```
<class name="Person" table="tperson" discriminator-value="PERSON">
    <id name="Id" column="id" type="integer">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <discriminator column="person_type" />
    <subclass name="Student" discriminator-value="STUDENT">
        <key column="id_person" />
        <subclass name="SchoolBoy" discriminator-value="SCHOOL_BOY">
            <join table="tstudent">
                <key column="id_person" />
            </join>
        </subclass>
        <subclass name="CollegeStudent" discriminator-value="COLLEGE_STUDENT">
            <join table="tstudent">
                <key column="id_person" />
            </join>
        </subclass>
    </subclass>
</class>
```

Now I want to introduce the **Course** entity, implementing a relation between courses and students. Of course, this is a many-to-many relation. Let's suppose I use a pivot table named tstudent_course, which contains students of both types **SchoolBoy** and **CollegeStudent**. This table contains a reference to the person itself and the course he's studying.

Now I want to differ between college and school students when I load the **Course** entity. I do it like that:

```
<set name="CollegeStudents" table="tstudent_course"
            inverse="true">
    <key>
        <column name="id_course" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <many-to-many entity-name="CollegeStudent">
        <column name="id_person" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-many>
</set>

<set name="SchoolStudents" table="tstudent_course"
            inverse="true">
    <key>
        <column name="id_course" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <many-to-many entity-name="SchoolBoy">
        <column name="id_person" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-many>
</set>
```

However, being the pivot table a table which contains references to every type of students, it tries to load every single student in my collections and I receive the next Exception:

```
Object with id: 2 was not of the specified subclass: 
   CollegeStudent (loaded object was of wrong class class SchoolBoy)
```

It seems Hibernate is doing the join whithout evaluating the concrete type of student I have and tries to inject an SchoolBoy in my collection of College Students.

What can I do to avoid that? Is it possible to stablish a kind of discrimination in the pivot table? Or do I have to create an specific pivot table for each kind of subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your set you can add a filter:

```
<set name="CollegeStudents" table="tstudent_course"
            inverse="true">
    <key>
        <column name="id_course" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <many-to-many entity-name="CollegeStudent" where="person_type='COLLEGE_STUDENT'">
        <column name="id_person" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-many>
</set>
```

IMHO the mapping would be better without that filter (just a set of all students).

Comment: I'm facing an error with that, person_type column doesn't seem to be available: `Unknown column in 'where clause'`. Is it looking for it in the tperson table or in the pivot table? I know it also can be done loading the whole student collection, but it's just to load only the values I need to iterate over, in fact why to load all the students if I only need specific cases? I'm working in a real time system and I need everything to be as fast as possible.

Comment: By the way, implementing it with two pivot tables (tstudent_college_course and tstudent_school_course) seems to work properly. Although I think it's not the best chance from DB relational view point.